# Groovy - No signature of method using parseDouble

Tags: groovy

I'm getting the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: AdjDriver.AdjustDriver() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double) values: [60.0, 0.25]
Possible solutions: AdjDriver(double, double)
```

Here's is the code I'm running in groovy console:

```
double d1
double d2

def double AdjDriver(double DriverVal, double PctAdj) {
    return  DriverVal = DriverVal + (DriverVal *PctAdj)
}

d1 = Double.parseDouble("60.00")
d2 = Double.parseDouble("0.25")

/* This works fine */

println AdjDriver(d1,d2)

/* This net line Throws the error:*/

println AdjustDriver( Double.parseDouble("60.00"),  Double.parseDouble("0.25"))
```

Comment: You haven't posted the definition of AdjustDriver. AdjDriver != AdjustDriver

Comment: That was it.   Darn typo.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `AdjustDriver` to `AdjDriver`. This is the function you defined.

By the way: Instead of `def double` write just `double`.